# Is this GLSL equivalent to this HLSL?

Tags: shaders, glsl, hlsl

I was wondering if the both shader codes are equivalent.
So the question is, is this GLSL

```
vNormal = mat3(FUSEE_ITMV[0].xyz, FUSEE_ITMV[1].xyz, FUSEE_ITMV[2].xyz) * fuNormal;
```

Equivalent to this HLSL?

```
float3x3 fMatrix = {FUSEE_ITMV[0].xyz,FUSEE_ITMV[1].xyz,FUSEE_ITMV[2].xyz};
output.normal = normalize(mul(input.normal,(float3x3)fMatrix));
```

Theoretical I'd say yes they are but I'm not sure. Can anyone verify that they are equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming your `FUSEE_ITMV` matrix in HLSL is the transpose of the `FUSEE_ITMV` GLSL matrix, otherwise you need to make sure it's transposed. GLSL `mat3` deals with the passed vectors as columns of the matrix. HLSL `float3x3` on the other hand deals with them as rows.

GLSL:

```
mat3 m( column0, column1, column2);
m[0]; // returs the first column
```

HLSL:

```
float3x3 m = float3x3(row0, row1, row2); // sets rows of matrix n
m[0]; // Returns first row.
```

As far as you are indexing you matrices in a uniform way, columns for columns and rows for rows, this will assign each column to its equivalent column in the glsl `mat3` and each row to its equivalent row in the glsl `float3x3`

Comment: No my HLSL FUSEE_ITMV isn't the transposed to the FUSEE_ITMV from GLSL.
I'm transposing the one from HLSL within my Engine before I render my frame, so after I created my InputLayout. 
Could these lead to another rendering?

Comment: I don't know about how you are doing it in your code, but as long as your GLSL is being passed a column matrix and your HLSL a row matrix, they are the same. In other words every column in GLSL matrix should be equivalent to every row in the same HLSL matrix.

Comment: @Rey I hope it worked!